# GitHub Pages is not serving PNG files

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

The documentation for `geoplot` is rendered via GitHub Pages, off of the `gh-pages` branch of its repository. However, some of the images on the following page fail to render: https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/quickstart/quickstart.html.

Take as an example the image `QuickStart_21_2.png` and the image `QuickStart_10_1.png`. Both of these files are located in the [`_images` folder](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/tree/gh-pages/_images) in the `gh-pages` branch of the repository, but whilst the former [is served correctly](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/_images/QuickStart_21_2.png), the latter [serves a 404](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/_images/QuickStart_10_1.png).

Why would these files not be rendered?

Comment: All images appear to be rendering properly when I checked [Quickstart](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/quickstart/quickstart.html) just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be due to some interesting dynamics around filename casing conventions and (probably) some kind of intermediate cache at GitHub. More details here: https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/175.